# new product added from admin takes time to show on site

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I tried to run a couple of tests for adding products from admin login and then checking whether new products are shown on site in real time. I found out that there is a delay of about 8-10 mins before new products are shown on the site frontend.

Is it due to ehcache configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SOLR indexing service is by default configured to run once every 60 minutes. This setting can be adjusted in the `common.properties` file, property name `solr.index.repeat.interval.` So to change the service to run every 3 minutes, the property would be set like this:

```
solr.index.repeat.interval=180000
```

The application has to be restarted for this setting to take effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing to exact location to change sorl reindex interval. But will 3 mins of time between consecutive reindex won't hit applications performance?

Comment: Depends on the number of products. The 3 minute setting is mainly for development purposes only, for production I would re-index once in 10 minutes, unless I had millions of products on the site.

Comment: Thanks again for this handsome piece of information :)

Answer (score 0):

no its the solr search engine. the time to show newly created products depends on how you have configured the reindexing job. look into the applicationContext of your webapp, there should be a  quartz job that triggers the reindexing

```
<bean id="rebuildIndexTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="rebuildIndexJobDetail" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="${solr.index.start.delay}" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="${solr.index.repeat.interval}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: This is a good information to have. But does solr search engine comes in picture even when I click a product category(like Hot Sauces, Merchandise in broadleaf demo application)?